# Caused by: com.google.gson.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: "<" (60), after : ""

Tags: json, gson, android, android-parser

In my android application I am facing a very strange error and cannot get into root of it. I making a network call and parsing the JSON response. But the application crashes and I receive the following error.

It occurs randomly and unable to reproduce the error. It would be very handy if some one who have faced this before could tell me what possibly could trigger this crash.

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Failed parsing JSON source: java.io.StringReader@40e13578 to Json
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:57)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:443)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:396)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:372)
    at com.xyz.getStaffFromJson(JsonUtils.java:201)
    at com.xyz.getMyDetails(WebAPI.java:666)
    at com.xyz.OptimisedSyncService.onHandleIntent(OptimisedSyncService.java:147)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
    Caused by: com.google.gson.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: \"<\" (60), after : \"\"
    at com.google.gson.JsonParserJavaccTokenManager.getNextToken(JsonParserJavaccTokenManager.java:1168)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParserJavacc.jj_ntk(JsonParserJavacc.java:635)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParserJavacc.parse(JsonParserJavacc.java:10)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:54)
    ... 10 more
    com.google.gson.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: \"<\" (60), after : \"\"
    at com.google.gson.JsonParserJavaccTokenManager.getNextToken(JsonParserJavaccTokenManager.java:1168)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParserJavacc.jj_ntk(JsonParserJavacc.java:635)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParserJavacc.parse(JsonParserJavacc.java:10)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:54)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:443)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:396)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:372)
    at com.xyz.getStaffFromJson(JsonUtils.java:201)
    at com.xyz.getMyDetails(WebrosterAPI.java:666)
    at com.xyz.OptimisedSyncService.onHandleIntent(OptimisedSyncService.java:147)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Sample response :
{"mcode":"123","mobilesettings":{"mobile":"07405123154","email":"rcb@rtc.com","telephone":"0174465599","timeout":20,"mail_address":"abc.gmail.com","mail_user":"mail.user@gmail.com","mail_password":"password","task_state":0,"force_task_reason":0,"allow_free_task_reason":1,"unsent_sync":10,"booking_sync":240,"default_scan_mode":0,"gps_enabled":1,"gps_poll_interval":5,"minimum_gps_accuracy":100.0,"allow_blank_aborted_reason":false,"allow_free_aborted_reason":true},"staff":{"json_class":"Staff","staff_id":1234,"title":"","fname":"rags","mname":"","sname":"rags","location_id":321,"pager":"","mobile":"07444456789","email":"abc@def.com","website":"","dob":null,"job_title":"","uid_ref":1,"dt_stamp":"Tue Feb 11 13:13:44 +0000 2014","pin_no":"","wroptions":0,"dt_created":"Wed Dec 04 16:13:08 +0000 2013","user_created":1,"pin_start":"1234","pin_end":"1234","payroll_report":"Payroll.xml","external_payroll_ref":"","payroll_export":"Payroll.sql","supplier":0,"is_saved":1}}

Comment: Take a look at the JSON you're parsing. The `""` part does seem weird...

Comment: Please share the sample JSON string that you are trying to parse.

Comment: Hi Braj, Please refer to thesample response added to the question. Any thoughts would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that while expecting a json response, i was receiving a html response from captive portal wifi like BT hot spot or Virgin media hot spots. Hence the parser failed and causing the error.